# Is [failed-missions] an interesting tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I just asked [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1325/why-space-shuttle-had-not-a-launch-escape-system) and I took the liberty of adding two tags. One is [failed-missions](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/failed-missions). Can this be interesting for filtering and for discussing causes and details about failed missions? With failed I mean at any phase: at launch-pad, in orbit, re-entering and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the use of plural in tag names could potentially suggest that broad questions are fine (they're not), I suggest we rather use tag names in singular, e.g. this one would then be [failed-mission](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/failed-mission). If we used the plural [failed-missions](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/failed-missions), we might invite questions that discuss multiple failed missions, or even request lists of them, which is often counterproductive.

In case singular and plural versions aren't semantically different, then I favor the singular versions. They still imply the same thing, even if the question later refers to it in plural, but is not necessarily so the other way around.

Otherwise, I think the tag is fine. We'll inevitably have also tags with a negative connotation, and [failed-missions](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/failed-missions) is not even as *strong* as some others we might see added in the near future, such as [casualty](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/casualty), [death](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/death), e.t.c.

Comment: Could you rename it to singular?

Comment: @trapo - I believe only moderators can do that. I've tried to rename tag "failed-missions" to singular "failed-mission" by double editing to exclude plural first, then include singular, but my mission failed LOL

Comment: can we add the singular tag, and then delete the plural tag? I won't try now - am away, so on an iPad

Comment: @RoryAlsop - It doesn't wanna work that way, it complains that the tag already exists in plural. I've tried. We'll need to wait until we get our own moderators, I guess. :|

Comment: we have one already - http://meta.space.stackexchange.com/users/545/gabe

Comment: @RoryAlsop - Ah interesting, didn't see. Then I suggest you flag in this thread something to bring this to his attention. ;)

Comment: Beta sites usually get an SE community person until pro-tems are assigned. Not sure when @gabe came onboard

Comment: @RoryAlsop - It couldn't have been long ago, I didn't yet see him in the chat. Talking of which, I see you're there... and me too, so why are we having this chat here? :))

Comment: @RoryAlsop Alas, Gabe is just [one of us](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/who-are-the-community-managers-and-what-do-they-do). We're still looking for volunteers to complete the initial mod line-up. :)

Comment: So, just to double-check... you guys want to replace [failed-missions] with [failed-mission]?

Comment: @AnnaLear - That's correct. Plural to singular. Thanks!

Comment: All done - failed-missions will now be remapped to failed-mission, although most people will probably just use failed-mission directly.

Comment: @AnnaLear - Thanks! Can you please add the [tag:status-completed] to this thread? Cheers! :)

Comment: @RoryAlsop You guys just dodged a bullet there! We're working on finding better mods :)

Comment: @Gabe - Dodging a bullet, riding a bullet, even slingshooting around a bullet... all in a day's work on [space.se]. We even use bulleted lists, when we feel particularly daring. :))

Comment: @TildalWave And you'd think space stuff would be more laser-inclined...